I have a problem with an Injection problem in .NET MAUI, someone could help me?
I'm working with .NET MAUI consuming a Web API project actually I'm new with this so any suggestion about it or documentation are welcome :).I want to implement in the back-code Login.xaml.cs the method but it doesn't work.
I realized the problem is in the injection of LoginService, because when i drop it from the constructor the app works but only the Login page as soon as I clicked at Iniciar Sesion the app stop and close. When I wrote the LoginService logeo in the constructor the app just run but any page is on the screen. I checked de MauiProgram.cs and did the enable of the injection, because i read it was necessary. Anyone coould help me. I'll be grateful :b
using ConsultoresMaui.Models;
using ConsultoresMaui.Services;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace ConsultoresMaui.Vistas
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly LoginService _loginService;

        public Login(LoginService logeo)
        {
            _loginService = logeo;
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void IniciarSesion(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var usuario= UsuarioEntry.Text;
            var password = PasswordEntry.Text;


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Por favor ingrese su usuario y contraseña", "OK");
                return;
            }
            var user = new Usuario
            {
                NombreUsuario = usuario,
                UserPassword = password
            };


            var isSuccess = await _loginService.LoginAsync(user);

            if (isSuccess)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Inicio());
            }
            else
            {

                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Credenciales inválidas", "OK");
            }

        }
    }


Here is my solution.
MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Login>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginService>();


